# Get a Modified File in Linux with Java on OpenSuse Leap?

Tags: java, linux

i need an approach with Java to make the Programm know when a File in Linux has been modified. I have tried Files.getLastModifiedTime(), BasicFileAttributes and lastModified. Unfortunately this has not work.

The Scenarios

Scenario A:

- an empty Textfile beeing copied from A to B Folder.
- then the same empty Textfile in A beeing edited and written something like "Hello World!!!" in an Editor and then copy this file again in Folder B.

Scenario B:

- an empty Textfile beeing copied from A to B Folder.
- then the same empty Textfile beeing copied again in Folder B.

*In Scenario A my Java Programm identify a modified File in Folder B. I use a timestamp in (dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:SS) to give it some Unique Identifikation when i relate this Timestamp with its filename as Strings.

*But in Scenario B my Java Programm identify this file also als modified, even though there hasnt been any changes to this Textfile, its the same and its empty in Folder B. I dont know which attribute to use in Java in order to make the programm know that this File has not been modified.(This only happened to me in Linux)

I use openSuse Leap for the Linux environment and Java openJdk 1.8 for my Programm.

As this Programm starts ill copy the 2 existing files in "/tmp/testfolder" to
"/tmp/testfolder/AFolder" with a Linux cp command.
It seems to me that openSUSE Leap doesnt save the Last modified data on its files,
because i get a new and same timestamp for values in Folder A and Folder B.
This doesnt happen in Linux Mint. Unfortunately my company uses openSuse Leap :(

My code:

```
 package com.company;
    
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
    
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    
    public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args ) 
        {
            File textFile1 = new File("/tmp/testfolder/TextFile1.txt");
            File textFile2 = new File("/tmp/testfolder/TextFile2.txt");
            File textFile1CopyInA = new File("/tmp/testfolder/AFolder/TextFile1.txt");
            File textFile2CopyInA = new File("/tmp/testfolder/AFolder/TextFile2.txt");
            File textFile1CopyInB = new File("/tmp/testfolder/BFolder/TextFile1.txt");
            File textFile2CopyInB = new File("/tmp/testfolder/BFolder/TextFile2.txt");
            File bfolder = new File("/tmp/testfolder/BFolder/");    
            try {
                System.out.println("Last Modified of File at testFolder" + textFile1.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile1.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                System.out.println("Last Modified of File at testFolder" + textFile2.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile2.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile1));
                    String data = "Hello World!!!";
                    writer.write(data);
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
            
            while(true) {
                
                if((textFile1CopyInA.exists())&&(textFile2CopyInA.exists())){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Last Modified of File in A" + textFile1CopyInA.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile1CopyInA.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                        System.out.println("Last Modified of File in A" + textFile2CopyInA.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile2CopyInA.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(textFile1CopyInA, bfolder);
                        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(textFile2CopyInA, bfolder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                if((textFile1CopyInB.exists())&&(textFile2CopyInB.exists())){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Last Modified of File in B " + textFile1CopyInB.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile1CopyInB.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                        System.out.println("Last Modified of File in B" + textFile2CopyInB.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " + Files.getLastModifiedTime(textFile2CopyInB.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in Advance!!

Comment: I don't think you can track this with file attributes. The file attributes do not track the content of a file. They only track information about the file's "meta" data, like when was the file modified. Copying one file over the other is a modification over the former.  It is just coincidence if the file's content does not change. If you want to check whether the *content* of a file changed then you have to use something else than attributes. One option would be to track the MD5 checksum of the file, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this solved completely my Problem. I used this Checksum from this link: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/sha-md5-file-checksum-hash/ and add it to my Project, it worked!!!